# How do I get Visual Studio 2008 to ignore trailing whitespace when I press END?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, whitespace

It's annoying in VS2008 when I press the `END` key, and my cursor jumps out to way beyond the end of the line of code, because I have trailing whitespace from a copy+paste or reformat.

I would like the `END` key to ignore whitespace. How can I best do this?

I thought of using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to catch `END` keypresses, and replace them with "`CTRL+E`, `\`, `END`" (That's "Delete Horizontal White Space", under Edit -> Advanced).

I'd like a less hacky solution if possible, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's my AutoHotkey script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
#IfWinActive, .* - Microsoft Visual Studio
End::Send {End}^e\
```

Guess I'll use that until someone posts a better answer :)

Comment: updated for 2010, change the last line to: 

End::Send {End}^k^\

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you want on the 'ignore' front, but you can do a *ctrl + delete* should delete all the white space. If not *contol + shift + left arrow* to highligh then *del* will fix it.

The format selection *ctrl + e, ctrl + f* should remove trailing white space. As per Paul's comment

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you want, but selecting the markup and doing "Format Selection" will remove the whitespace...